# Item not highlighted in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a navigation drawer. I have created it but the problem is that when i open the app the first time, the fragment is displayed in the content area but it is not highlighted in the navigation drawer.

This is code i'm using:

```
    package com.hfad.evenit;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import com.hfad.evenit.Fragments.FourthFragment;
    import com.hfad.evenit.Fragments.SecondFragment;
    import com.hfad.evenit.Fragments.ThirdFragment;
    import com.hfad.evenit.Fragments.TopFragment;

    public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

        String []FragmentTitles;
        ListView DrawerList;
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home);

            FragmentTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fragment_titles);
            DrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            DrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, FragmentTitles));

            DrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selectItem(position);
                }
            });


            selectItem(0);
            DrawerList.setSelection(0);


            drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
          drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            drawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerList);
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_share).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            if(drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            {
                return  true;
            }
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        public void selectItem(int position)
        {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch(position)
            {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new TopFragment();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new SecondFragment();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new ThirdFragment();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new FourthFragment();
                    break;
                default:
                    fragment = new TopFragment();
            }

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();

            setActionBarTitle(position);

            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerList);

        }

        public void setActionBarTitle(int position)
        {
            String title;
            title = FragmentTitles[position];
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `setItemChecked(int position, boolean value)` method?

Comment: Thanks man you are a life saver.

Comment: Glad to hear that, also check my answer about the Choice mode if you hadn't already set it to single.

Answer (score 1):

The method you should use for changing the items state to "highlighted" or currently activated is `setItemChecked(int position, boolean value)`. It's best to place it in your `selectItem` method so that the "highlighted" item changes once your `SelectItem` method is called.

You might also want to consider setting the listView's choice mode to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE so that only one item can be in an active state at a given time.

```
drawerList.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Around here...

```
public void selectItem(int position) {

    ...

    setActionBarTitle(position);

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerList);
}
```

Adding `DrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);` may work.

```
public void selectItem(int position) {

    ...

    setActionBarTitle(position);

    DrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true); // <== add this line

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerList);
}
```

Actually I'm not using Navigation Drawer of the Android Studio's project template but using NavigationView (it is recommended for ease to use), recently. If my answer is invalid, please forget this.